# Custom QCompleter strange behavior

Tags: c++, qt, qcompleter

I all, I just follow this great example:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-customcompleter.html
I copy the code exactly except some change with the modelFromFile method, here is it:

```
QAbstractItemModel *MainWindow::modelFromFile(const QString& fileName&#41;
 {
     QStringList words;
     words
     << "break"
     << "default"
     << "func"
     << "interface"
     << "select"
     << "case"
     << "defer"
     << "go"
     << "map"
     << "struct"
     << "chan"
     << "else"
     << "goto"
     << "package"
     << "switch"
     << "const"
     << "fallthrough"
     << "if"
     << "range"
     << "type"
     << "continue"
     << "for"
     << "import"
     << "return"
     << "var";
     return new QStringListModel(words, completer);
 }
```

The strange thing is when I type "fal" I'm waiting for "fallthrough" pop out, but I see nothing. It can work with "break" and some but not all words.
I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 and my partner with Ubuntu 12.04 get this behavior.
Qt Creator 2.4.1
Based on Qt 4.8.0 (32 bit)

Comment: My only suggestion at this point is to use documentation for your version of qt (4.8), not for the upcoming 5.0. There might have been incompatible changes to QCompleter...

Comment: just test it with 4.8 version, still the same, anyone has the same issue like me?

Comment: Just a guess: maybe, sort the list?..

Comment: May be this strange behavior comes from unsorted string-list, check it with sorted string list.

Comment: Oh Yes! It work with the sorted list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QStringListModel is able to complete word when list given in argument is sorted list. Your list is unsorted, so it has right not to work :)

Comment: Lets say If I have 3 sorted List, can anyway I can use my lists with completer without merge and sort them agian?

Comment: You have to merge and sort them because other way QCOmpleter will find word for each list, so u'll get three words instead of one.